# live 'pagecreate' calling multiple times Dynamic pages using URL parameter in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery mobile with phonegap to create an iPhone application. I am passing dynamic id in URL to get data from database and fill the fields on page when page loaded.

```
$.mobile.changePage( "child-form-page.html?id=1");
```

It work first time fine and data-roll div id live function get called

```
$('#childForm').live('pagecreate',function(event){ 
  //Fetch data and fill fields based on ID i get in url
});
```

But when I submit the form and move to next form by using the same page `$.mobile.changePage( "child-form-page.html?id=2");` is trigger `$('#childForm').live` function twice and data get lost.

Comment: I have provided a solution for you in my answer below, if you need any more help contact me through my email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide us with more code I can only offer you a fix for your problem. jQuery Mobiles working nature can cause us some problems while binding events. jQuery event binding don't have a check that will prevent multiple event (same event, for example click event) binding to a single element.

This can be prevented in few ways and I will enumerate all of them for you, but I think your problem is not related to multiple event binding because unlike jQuery jQuery Mobile page event binding will prevent multiple binding and in that case you will find your solution at a bottom of my answer.

**Solution 1:**

Remove event before you bind it:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-button').die().live('click', function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

In case you have different events bound to an object:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){    
    $('#test-button').die('click').live('click', function(e) {
        alert('Button click');
    });    
});
```

**Solution 2:**

Use a jQuery Filter selector, like this:

```
$('#carousel div:Event(!click)').each(function(){
    //If click is not bind to #carousel div do something
});
```

Because event filter is not a part of official jQuery framework it can be found here: http://www.codenothing.com/archives/2009/event-filter/

In a nutshell, if speed is your main concern then Solution 2 is much better then Solution 1.

**Solution 3:**

A new one, probably an easiest of them all.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#page', function(event){  
    if(event.handled !== true) // This will prevent event triggering more then once
    {
        // Some code
        event.handled = true;
    }
    return false;                
});
```

Tnx to sholsinger for this solution: http://sholsinger.com/archive/2011/08/prevent-jquery-live-handlers-from-firing-multiple-times/

**pageChange event quirks - triggering twice**

Sometimes pagechange event can trigger twice and it does not have anything to do with the problem mentioned before.

The reason the pagebeforechange event occurs twice is due to the recursive call in changePage when toPage is not a jQuery enhanced DOM object. This recursion is dangerous, as the developer is allowed to change the toPage within the event. If the developer consistently sets toPage to a string, within the pagebeforechange event handler, regardless of whether or not it was an object an infinite recursive loop will result. The pageload event passes the new page as the page property of the data object (This should be added to the documentation, it's not listed currently). The pageload event could therefore be used to access the loaded page.

In few words this is happening because you are sending additional parameters through pageChange.

Example:

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" href="#care-plan-view?id=9e273f31-2672-47fd-9baa-6c35f093a800&amp;name=Sat"><h3>Sat</h3></a>
```

To fix this problem use any page event listed in chapter [Page events transition order](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/) (this is my other answer/article about jQuery Mobile page event binding).

Answer (score 1):

If you have your `<script>` tag up in the `<header>` section, your event will only bind on the first page load. If you have your `<script>` tag as the first child of your `<div role="page">` tag, it will be bound over and over.

Details at the bottom of this page:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Also, ensure you are not using `$(document).ready();`
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that if you perform DOM manipulation, for example through jQuery in your `pagecreate` handler, that you inadvertently trigger such behavior.

```
<div data-role="page" id="somePage"> 
  <div id="elem"/>
</div>
```

And the handler:

```
$('#somePage').on("pagecreate", function() {    
  var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('t');                                                       
  $('#elem').append(table);
});
```

Due to the fact that the `elem` div is not defined as `<div id="elem"></div>`, but `<div id="elem"/>`, this leads to trouble.

So, it might very well have nothing to do with the dynamic id you want to pass.